# CC1101 Transceiver pair not working when relatively close to each other

Tags: rf, wireless

I have a pair of cheap *CC1101* boards transmitting at 433MHz.

(1): One oddity that first led me to believe that they weren't functional is the fact that they do not receive data when they are within approx. 1m of each other.

The antenna is mounted in parallel to the PCBs ground plane.

*The issue could be resolved by setting the transmitting power to "PA_LowPower".*

**What is the reason behind this kind of behavior, why does the communication fail under the described circumstances (1)? Why can't the two devices communicate properly when in "Long Distance" mode?**

[image: This is the mentioned module]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very simple: receiver overload.

RF receivers are sensitive devices, which means you've got some amplifier in there that converts a very low-amplitude signal to a signal that is many thousand times as high in amplitude.

Now, this amplification ideally happens linearly, i.e. output = k · input, no matter how high or low the input.

If you, however, have an input that drives the amplifier to saturation (for example, k = 10000, input = 0.01 V, but only 2 V supply voltage: you can't achieve output = k · input = 100 V), then nonlinearity happens, and that means (among other things) that different frequencies in the received signal mix, and the resulting mishmash of things isn't decodable.

Just like you won't be able to understand what is said if we strapped you to a concert speaker box, set the amplifier to max power, overdrive it, and deafen you with something screamed into your ear, the receiver simply can't handle signals that are "too loud".

So, yeah, reduce transmit power if you don't have the loss due to free space distance, or reduce the receive gain.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now that I think of it, it makes a lot more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative possibilityr:

At 433 MHz, the wavelength is about 70 cm and when antennas are in the near field of each other they don't receive fully-fledged EM waves but individual E and H fields and these can interact with the partly fledged EM wave and produce cancellation at many points an angles.

I'm not saying this is happening with your set up and indeed, it may be as Marcus has stated.

Comment: good point! To diagnose that possibility, moving either side by a couple of cm would increase reception.

Comment: *"partly fledged EM wave"*?!? What have you been smoking? Are you saying that you can find a position/orientation of two antennas of the type pictured within the near field where there is no coupling whatsoever? I.e., total cancellation of both the E and H fields?

Comment: One that hasn't reached the impedance of free space i.e. is out of balance in terms of ratio of E to H.

Comment: @DaveTweed look at antenna as impedance transformer between let's say 50Ω trans line and free space. Now, you build a cap/coil/transformer thingie from two antennas in reactive near field. Might totally lead to a wildly increased tx-side reflection coeff?

Comment: @MarcusMüller: How would it do that? The fields associated with these antennas are just not that complicated. There's no way you can eliminate both inductive and capacitive coupling simultaneously.

Comment: You could still consider the antenna pair as complex impedance, and by choosing the worst distance convert the receiver's 50 Ohm to e.g. an open end that sinks very little energy?

Comment: @MarcusMüller: Not even remotely possible. You're completely ignoring the part of the transmitter field that is NOT intercepted by the receive antenna and is lost to free space.

Comment: True, but that energy also isn't sunk into the receiver?